# Null Values in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework

```
var query = from section in load_sections.Sections
            join course in load_sections.Courses
                on section.Course_Id equals course.Course_Id
            join faculty in load_sections.Faculties
                on section.Faculty_Id equals faculty.Faculty_Id
            select section;
```

I have some null values in my section.Faculty_Id which will not be equal to any row in faculty.Faculty_Id and it is just returning the records where section.Faculty_Id is not null...If section.Faculty_Id is not null, then it must return the other remaining fields of Table Courses

Comment: Why do you join with `faculty` if you only select `section`? Looks like removing the join would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't drop the join on `faculty` for whatever reason, you'll have to construct an outer join:

```cs
var query = from section in load_sections.Sections
            join course in load_sections.Courses
                on section.Course_Id equals course.Course_Id
            join faculty in load_sections.Faculties
                on section.Faculty_Id equals faculty.Faculty_Id into faculties
            from f in faculties.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select section;
```

This executes a `GroupJoin` with `Faculties`. The effect of the subsequent `from f in faculties` is that the grouping is flattened again by a `SelectMany`. `.DefaultIfEmpty()` creates the outer join.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize that would have any effect. I'm still confused by this question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks. So am I. It's probably not the whole story.